# Происхождение слова "уповать"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

"Уповать" - надеяться на кого-то,  на что-то. " Упоительный" - ублажающий(в словарях такого  синонима нет, это моё восприятие, - несущий благо), восхитительный,  чарующий.
Родственны ли эти слова между собой?  Могут ли они происходить от слов: "поить", "пить"?

Answer (score 2):

Слова, скорее всего, не являются родственными.

**УПОЕНИЕ**
<состояние восторга, восхищения>, <блаженство>. Заимствовано из ст.-сл. яз. Абстрактный смысл психологического состояния чел. развился из конкретного знач. слова. Ст.-сл. сущ. упоений образовано с пом. суф. отвлеч. имен -uj-e (как чтение) от страд, прич. с суф. -ен- упоенъ глаг. ***упоити* <напоить, насытить>**, в свою очередь производного с прист. у- со знач. завершенности действия (как ублажить) от глаг. пойти <давать пить, насыщать>, это **понудительное действие (каузатив) глаг. пити. См. пить**

[http://moyslovar.ru/slovari/etimolog_slovar/slovo/УПОЕНИЕ](http://moyslovar.ru/slovari/etimolog_slovar/slovo/%D0%A3%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95)

УПОВАТЬ (из словаря Шанского)

**УПОВАТЬ.** Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где упъвати — преф. производное от пъвати "**надеяться, полагаться**", суф. образования от той же основы, что польск. pwa "надежда",

УПОВАТЬ( из словаря Фасмера)

**Не имеет достоверной этимологии.** Сравнивают с др.-инд. pávatē, punā́ti "очищает, искупает, проясняет";

(Пизани ("Раidеiа", 12, No 5, 1957, стр. 308) считает это слово очень **древним германизмом**, ср. нем. hoffen "надеяться". – Т.)

Черных считает, что у слова *уповать* и.-е. корень **pou - очищать**. Развитие значение: приносить очистительную жертву, надеяться на божественную милость.